# Postman stuck on "sending request"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postman

Below is my code for establishing connect with database and query. it was working till yesterday but today if I test on postman getting sending request like the below screenshot. For database connection, I am using Heroku
[image]

```
import pool from './pool';

export default {
  /**
   * DB Query
   * @param {object} req
   * @param {object} res
   * @returns {object} object
   */
  query(quertText, params) {
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.query(quertText, params)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("tes")
          resolve(res);

        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("err")
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: Could you add controller/router?

Comment: It seems like Heroku issue.

Comment: this issue is resolved after updating pg.